# Timeout exception leaving Windows Service unresponsive

Tags: c#, .net, exception, windows-services

I have a windows service that does the following things:

1. Connects to a datasource OnStart.
2. Calls a method to get the data from the datasource every 5 seconds and saves it to the database.
3. Calls a 3rd party web service to process the data every 5 seconds.

The setup:

Both points 2 and 3 are called on the elapse of the same timer. Occasionally, the 3rd party web service times out. In such case, we catch the exception, log it in our database and then don't throw it again. The idea is that we want to retry calling the web service when the timer elapses again as improving the 3rd party service is outside our control and in any case this doesn't happen often. Here is some pseudo code for ProcessData():

```
private bool ProcessData()
{
    bool hasBeenProcessed = false;

    try
    {
        // Call web service
        // If successful
        hasBeenProcessed = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Log exception
    }

    return hasBeenProcessed;
}
```

The issue:

Our windows service stops working altogether even though the exception was handled and not rethrown. Forget about step 3, we can't see any data in the database that should be done as part of Step 2. Ideally speaking we don't want data collection to be impacted because of issues in data processing. The service itself shows as Running in the Service Manager. Stopping the service from the Service manager doesn't work though.

Question:

While we are now separating these two things into two different services, I was trying to find out what's going wrong in the current logic? Why is the windows service becoming unresponsive?

Comment: where is the exception being handled can you ad or show the logging logic that you are currently implementing ..? based on the code you have shown your method call does nothing

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the querying for data and calling the web service with data is taking longer than 5 seconds, so that your timer events are starting to pile up on each other.

Consider using a variable to track wheter or not you're in the middle of processing data before you try to process it again. Something like:

```
private bool _processingData = false;

private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{       
    if (!_processingData)
    {
        _processingData = true;

        QueryForData();
        ProcessData();

        _processingData = false;
    }
}
```